# How to contact php var with text for use on new php var name?

Tags: php

How to contact php var with text for use on new php var name ?

I have this input

```
<input type="text" name="test_1" value="test">
```

and this is my php code

```
$i = "1";
$input_value = $_POST["{'test_' . $i}"];
echo $input_value;
```

But i get blank value.

How can i do ?

Comment: `$_POST["test_{$i}"]` but why not just access like `$_POST["test_1"]`?

Comment: @ Lawrence Cherone - this code is a part of my project. I have to use code look like `$_POST["test_{$i}"]`

Comment: whats the point of assigning `$i` as variable if you can just type `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this bit of code you should concatanate outside of the double quotes

```
$_POST["test_" . $i];
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are getting blank value because "." is also getting concatenated in the parameter name and so you are getting wrong param name.
Try this**

```
 $input_value = "{test_$i}";
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions will trigger and error if the post key is undefined. A solution to this could be (requires php7):

```
$i = 1;
$input_value = $_POST['test_' . $i] ?? NULL;
```

PHP < 7

```
$i = 1;
$input_value = isset($_POST['test_' . $i]) ? $_POST['test_' . $i] : NULL;
```

or use a if statement with `array_key_exists` / `isset` / `empty`.